# Oracle SQL developer questions for interview

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, constraints, ddl

I have started to use constraints and would like to know which constraints can be used as a composite key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, we have

- not null
- primary key - can be composite
- unique key - can be composite
- foreign key - can be composite
- check

constraints.

Here's [Oracle 11g *constraint*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52163) documentation. Search the page for "composite" for more info.